# PowerShell Issue regarding entering a PS Session and setting permissions

Tags: powershell, sysinternals

I am currently making a script to create a folder which then creates an AD group and links them together. I then connect to our server in the data centre to set the permissions.

To do this I need to enter a PSSession and find the folder and set the permissions. Unfortunately, it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Script

```
#Get ADM Credentials
$Cred = Get-Credential

# PowerShell's New-Item creates a folder
$Name = Read-Host "What is the name of the folder?"
$Location = Read-Host "What is the folder path? i.e B:\Collaboration\"
New-Item -Path $Location -Name $Name -ItemType "directory"
#Invoke-Item $Location

# Powershell creates an AD group
$Groupname = Read-Host "What is the group name? i.e. SS COLLABORATION BEN"
New-ADGroup -path "OU=StorSimple Centralisation Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Northgate PLC,DC=northgatevehiclehire,DC=net" -Name $Groupname -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $Groupname -Description "Access to $Location" -Credential $cred


#Connect to StudFS01
$Folderpath = Read-Host "What is the path of the folder in StudFS e drive? i.e. Vehicle Sales\TOM Information" 
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Set-Location -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$folderpath

#Set Permissions
$rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("northgatevehiclehire.net\Domain Admins","FullControl","Allow")
$rule2=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("northgatevehiclehire.net\StorSimple Centralisation Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
$rule3=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("$Groupname","Modify","Allow")
$acl = Get-ACL E:\CentralisedData\Data\$folderpath
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule,$rule2,$rule3)
Set-ACL -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$folderpath -AclObject $acl
```

Error Im getting is below

Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'E' does not exist.
At C:\Users\ben.curtis-haigh\Documents\New Security Group Script.ps1:19 char:1
+ Set-Location -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$folderpath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Get-ACL : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'E' does not exist.
At C:\Users\ben.curtis-haigh\Documents\New Security Group Script.ps1:25 char:8
+ $acl = Get-ACL E:\CentralisedData\Data\$folderpath
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:String) [Get-Acl], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\ben.curtis-haigh\Documents\New Security Group Script.ps1:26 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($rule,$rule2,$rule3)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Set-Acl : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AclObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\ben.curtis-haigh\Documents\New Security Group Script.ps1:27 char:62
+ Set-ACL -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$folderpath -AclObject $acl
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand`

Thanks

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get an error message? Have you tried each of the steps manually to see where things don't match your expectations?

Comment: if You enter-pssession and from there want to access some network share  - You can be having this double hop credential delegation problem ?

Comment: @Tomek If `E:\\` is a share, this would be pretty obviously a double-hop problem.

Comment: I believe the problem here is that Enter-PSSession is meant for interactive use, not inside a script. Once you enter the session the rest of the script probably isn't executing. You'll want to use `Invoke-Command` against your PSSession instead.

Comment: Hello All,
Thanks all for your help, really appreciate it. I have added the error into the post. @JonDechiro the invoke command didnt work.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I have tried going through manually and its the last  bit (set-location) and enter PS-Session

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Enter-PSSession which is meant for interactive use, you need to establish a new PSSession and then use Invoke-Command against it. Something like this:

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
  <CODE TO EXECUTE ON REMOTE SYSTEM HERE>
}
```

If you need to pass parameters/variables, you have two choices. The easiest (in newer versions of PowerShell) is the using statement like this:

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
   Set-Location -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$using:Folderpath
}
```

Another option is to pass your arguments with -ArgumentList and use Param() in the script block like this:

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ArgumentList $Folderpath -ScriptBlock {
   Param($Folderpath)
   Set-Location -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$Folderpath
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Dechiro

Answer (score 0):

```
    Instead of Enter-PSSession which is meant for interactive use, you need to establish a new PSSession and then use Invoke-Command against it. Something like this:

$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
  <CODE TO EXECUTE ON REMOTE SYSTEM HERE>
}
If you need to pass parameters/variables, you have two choices. The easiest (in newer versions of PowerShell) is the using statement like this:

$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
   Set-Location -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$using:Folderpath
}
Another option is to pass your arguments with -ArgumentList and use Param() in the script block like this:

$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName Studfs01 -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ArgumentList $Folderpath -ScriptBlock {
   Param($Folderpath)
   Set-Location -Path E:\CentralisedData\Data\$Folderpath
}
```